# Prolog Undefined Procedure

Tags: prolog

I'm trying to to get a list of three items with their relevant information based on a collection of information:

```
product(I):-
    I = [_,_,_,_], %Type,Brand,Category,Value
    cheaper(item(apple,_,_),item(_,kay,_,_),I),
    cheaper(item(bar,_,_,_),item(_,_,fruit,_),I),
    member(item(_,kay,_,2),I),
    member(item(apple,granny,_,_),I),
    member(item(bar,_,chocolate,_),I),
    /* Below not given */
    member(item(cracker,_,_,_),I),
    member(item(_,_,biscuit,_),I),
    member(item(_,_,_,4),I),
    member(item(_,_,_,5),I).

cheaper(X,Y,H) :- %Used to determine the item values
    item(X,_,_,A),
    item(Y,_,_,B),
    A<B.
```

When I try running it I encounter an error:

```
?- product(I).
ERROR: cheaper/3: Undefined procedure: item/4
Exception: (8) item(item(apple, _G3604, _G3605), _G3651, _G3652, _G3653) ?
```

I understand that `item` isn't a procedure, however what can I used for checking the value for apple against the value for bar?

Comment: You have defined it with two arguments, not with three. This is what the error message is telling you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the obvious note, you're calling cheaper wrong once:

```
 cheaper(item(apple,_,_),item(_,kay,_,_),I),
         ↑
         Only three values, not four.
```

If `item` isn't a procedure, you mustn't call it, but use destructuring.
Also you want those items you're checking with cheaper to be part of the list, right? If so, you'll have to check that. And you can use unification to extract the values that you need:

```
cheaper(X,Y,I) :- 
  member(X,I),
  member(Y,I),
  [item(_,_,_,A),item(_,_,_,B)] = [X,Y],
  A<B.
```

Now you'll get some errors regarding not instantiated argument. That's because you are checking not (yet) set variables if they are greater than each other. To avoid this, move the `cheaper/3` calls to the end of your clause body:

```
product(I):-
    I = [_,_,_,_], %Type,Brand,Category,Value
    member(item(_,kay,_,2),I),
    member(item(_,_,_,4),I),
    member(item(_,_,_,5),I),
    member(item(apple,granny,_,_),I),
    member(item(bar,_,chocolate,_),I),
    /* Below not given */
    member(item(cracker,_,_,_),I),
    member(item(_,_,biscuit,_),I),
    cheaper(item(apple,_,_,_),item(_,kay,_,_),I), % note the 4th argument
    cheaper(item(bar,_,_,_),item(_,_,fruit,_),I).
```

With this, you'll get one solution and then it fails with an error. This is, because you only give three values for the price slot and you have four items and prolog will check `A > 2`.

Sorry, in my other answer I didn't look for what the poster was trying to achieve and I think that this is better than a complete reedit. (glorious SO mods let me know if I'm wrong)

Comment: Thank you so much for the very informative response, it did the trick!